# AWS StartSpeechSynthesisTaskRequest

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-polly

Currently using AWS services to create a PCM audio file by using Polly and storing it, into S3 bucket. The application is doing all that using AWS lambda.

I am using, "StartSpeechSynthesisTaskRequest", which allows the user to, create a request to amazon Polly and have the file delivered straight into a designated S3 bucket, chosen by the user.

The problem that I am having is that, once the code has been ran, I end up with a file name like so:

"MY_FILE_NAME.a1f9999f-f00r-6h45-j2ks-pd7fcc9sfw77.pcm"

What I wanted was:

"MY_FILE_NAME.pcm"

Why is this extra bit happening? has anyone got an answer to this issue?

I have posted the code below.

```
StartSpeechSynthesisTaskRequest startSpeechSynthesisRequest = new StartSpeechSynthesisTaskRequest()
                        // Required parameters
                        .withOutputFormat(PCM_FORMAT)
                        .withOutputS3BucketName(s3BucketName) <--- S3 bucket location/name
                        .withText(GREETING_FORMAT)
                        .withVoiceId(EMMA_VOICE_ID)
                        // Optional parameters
                        .withOutputS3KeyPrefix("MY_FILE_NAME") <--- my file desired name
                        .withEngine(NEURAL_ENGINE)
                        .withLanguageCode(ENGB_LANGUAGE_CODE)
                        .withSampleRate(SAMPLE_RATE)
                        .withTextType(SSML_TEXT_TYPE);
                pollyClient.startSpeechSynthesisTask(startSpeechSynthesisRequest);
```

Update:

If a I print "startSpeechSynthesisRequest", after it has been built with all the parameters, it will print the "withOutputS3KeyPrefix" exactly as I wanted. the problem is arising between polly and S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it, but you are getting what you asked for.  The output file from Polly is the requestId.  You are asking for a prefix for the S3 object, which is prepended to the Polly object.

If I run this:

```
aws polly start-speech-synthesis-task \
--voice-id Joanna \
--output-format mp3 \
--output-s3-bucket-name BUCKET \
--text "This audio sample was created using Amazon Polly and the AWS Command Line Interface." \
--region us-west-2
```

The response back is

```
{
    "SynthesisTask": {
        "TaskId": "020437c3-256f-4cd4-97d5-6785a8e477f4",
        "TaskStatus": "scheduled",
        "OutputUri": "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/020437c3-256f-4cd4-97d5-6785a8e477f4.mp3",
        "CreationTime": 1584849572.835,
        "RequestCharacters": 84,
        "OutputFormat": "mp3",
        "TextType": "text",
        "VoiceId": "Joanna"
    }
}
```

Notice the output URI- the file name is the TaskId.

If I add the S3KeyPrefix

```
aws polly start-speech-synthesis-task \
--voice-id Joanna \
--output-format mp3 \
--output-s3-bucket-name BUCKET \
--output-s3-key-prefix MY_FILE_NAME \
--text "This audio sample was created using Amazon Polly and the AWS Command Line Interface." \
--region us-west-2
```

This yields the response

```
{
    "SynthesisTask": {
        "TaskId": "c887dc20-998e-47e3-9eaf-47db32aa2aa9",
        "TaskStatus": "scheduled",
        "OutputUri": "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/MY_FILE_NAME.c887dc20-998e-47e3-9eaf-47db32aa2aa9.mp3",
        "CreationTime": 1584849928.825,
        "RequestCharacters": 84,
        "OutputFormat": "mp3",
        "TextType": "text",
        "VoiceId": "Joanna"
    }
}
```

this confirms what you are seeing.  So, my examples show doing this using the CLI, but all the S3KeyPrefix does is prepend the text to the Polly generated file name.  there is no method to define the actual file name.

When you submit your speech synthesis task, you should capture the response, which will tell you TaskId, which you know is going to be the file name in S3 once the task is finished.  You can then monitor the status and when it is done, change the file name to whatever you want it to be.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Amazon Polly adds that cryptic `TaskId` onto the end of the filename. There's nothing you can do about it.

If you want to, you can rename it once it's done. But you'll have to find out how to wait for the Polly `SynthesisTask` to complete, and how to rename a file in S3. I'm currently struggling to find any javascript docs on waiting for the task to complete.

Comment: You'll have to use the [`GetSpeechSynthesisTaskCommand`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-polly/classes/getspeechsynthesistaskcommand.html) and then analyse the result. As part of the result you get a [`GetSpeechSynthesisTaskCommandOutput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-polly/interfaces/getspeechsynthesistaskcommandoutput.html) which contains a [`SynthesisTask`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-polly/interfaces/synthesistask-2.html) object. This contains the `TaskStatus` property.